# How to print a List<T> as a <table> with 5 columns using <c:forEach>

Tags: jsp, foreach, html-table, jstl

My goal is to display my data in database just like in the image below.

[image]

I am using JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

```
<c:forEach items="${table}" var="table">
    <img height="70" src="${table.images}" />
    Table ${table.tableId}
</c:forEach>
```

How can I print a `<table>` with 5 columns?

Comment: Do you want just to display 5 items per row, or you need extra space behind the first and the third column?

Comment: 5 items per row. Sorry. I did not do properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="row" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <c:if test="${rowCounter.count % 5 == 1}">
      <tr>
    </c:if>
    <td><img src="${row.imageUrl}"/><br/>Table ${rowCounter.count}</td>
    <c:if test="${rowCounter.count % 5 == 0||rowCounter.count == fn:length(values)}">
      </tr>
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach >
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but there is a error. the error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@609f3e95 of type class javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to Number

Comment: Sorry forget to add `.count` to `rowCounter` variables, I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! Able to view it. However, right now first row is only 4. second row is 5, third row is 5 and forth row is 1. is there a way to make all the row 5?

Comment: Furtheremore, I have also have data retrieve from database. As you seen on the image above, there is word "Table 1". I tried to put td><img src="${row}"/></td> <td><img src="${row.tableName}"/></td> . However it just show on the side of the image. is there a way to put BELOW of the image?

Comment: Well `${rowcounter.count}` is not zero based, it is 1 based. I edited the answer again.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! :) However, there is one more thing. Probably you didn't saw the comment.. it is ok..  let me asked you once more "Furtheremore, I have also have data retrieve from database. As you seen on the image above, there is word "Table 1". I tried to put td><img src="${row}"/></td> <td><img src="${row.tableName}"/></td> . However it just show on the side of the image. is there a way to put BELOW of the image?" quoted from the last comment

Comment: What about the new update using a `<br/>` tag inside `<td>` tags? (I've updated the answer again).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45052/discussion-between-amir-pashazadeh-and-newbieinjava)